# Turning QueryParam into PathParam changes

Tags: java, json, network-programming

I want to replace all QueryParam implementation with PathParam ones and I;m not quite sure how to do so for the Rest Web Client.

The given code is this

```
@Path("/ErgoRest")
public class ErgoRestService {

@Contextprivate 
UriInfo context;

public WordsRestService() {}@
GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public String getJson(@QueryParam ("fname") String v1,
                      @QueryParam ("sname") String v2) {
                      @QueryParam ("address") String v3) {
// code ...// code ...// return ...}

@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void putJson(String content) {}
```

and for the Server its this

```
public class ErgoRestClient {
    private WebTarget webTarget;
    private Client client;
    private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:9090/WebErgoRest/webresources";

    public ErgoRestClient() {
        client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient();
        webTarget = client.target(BASE_URI).path("/ErgoRest");
    }

    public void putJson(Object requestEntity) throws ClientErrorException {
        webTarget.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                 .put(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(requestEntity, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }

    public String getJson(String var1, String var2, String var3) throws ClientErrorException {
        WebTarget resource = webTarget;

        if (var1 != null) {
            resource = resource.queryParam("fname", var1);
        } else {
            resource = resource.queryParam("fname", "Markos");
        }

        if (var2 != null) {
            resource = resource.queryParam("sname", var2);
        } else {
            resource = resource.queryParam("sname", "Botsaris");
        }

        if (var3 != null) {
            resource = resource.queryParam("address", var3);
        } else {
            resource = resource.queryParam("address", "Souli");
        }

        return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
    }

    public void close() {
        client.close();
    }
}
```

For the client i changed it into this

```
@Path("/ErgoRest")
public class ErgoRestService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{fname}/{sname}/{address}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getJson(@PathParam("fname") String v1, 
                          @PathParam("sname") String v2, 
                          @PathParam("address") String v3) {
        // code ...
        // code ...
        // return ...
    }

    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void putJson(String content) {}
}
```

For the server, i know i only have to change the getJason method. Do i get rid of all resources nd use an entirely different thing like resolve.Template or do something else?